# Two question about a decision tree algorithm I found online

Tags: machine-learning, references, cart, algorithms

I am trying to learn decision trees but it has been difficult because the examples are extremely long and tedious and everybody seems to have a different algorithm in mind

[image]

After some digging I found  a reliable set of notes online. However, I have the following two questions

1. What algorithm is this?
2. What is the meaning of $\mathbb{I}$?

It would be great if anyone can clarify this.

Here are the notes: [http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~flaxman/HT17_lecture13.pdf](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Eflaxman/HT17_lecture13.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The tree process exposed here is the [CART](https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-and-regression-trees-for-machine-learning/) algorithm. Another [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/cart-classification-and-regression-trees-for-clean-but-powerful-models-cc89e60b7a85) covering it.

The II is an [indicator function](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/indicator-functions). It basically means 1 if xxx else 0.

Beta is the probability of going either way compared to the splitting parameter